# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' in plt.scatter

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, svm

I don't get the following error

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

I tried all the possible solution, but I can't figure it out.

this is my array:

```
instances=np.array([[0,10],
                            [1,3],
                            [3,4],
                            [3,5],
                            [5,5],
                            [5,6],
                            [6,-5],
                            [5,8]])
```

and I have a loop here:

```
for p in instances:                
    Pred=clf.predict([p])

    print(p[0])    
    print(Pred)

    plt.scatter(p[0], p[1], s=200, marker='*', c=self.colors[Pred])
return Pred
```

the output is this:

```
0    
[0.]
```

Comment: Honestly I can't figure out what your question is here. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: You cannot use `return Pred` outside a function.

Answer (score 1):

`Pred` is a numpy array. It cannot be used as an index in `self.colors[Pred]`. You should use `self.colors[int(Pred[0])]`.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the context of your error, but I'm assuming it's something like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49840380/5353461).

It so, then change:

```
    plt.scatter(p[0], p[1], s=200, marker='*', c=self.colors[Pred])
```

to:

```
    plt.scatter(p[0], p[1], s=200, marker='*', c=self.colors[Pred].ravel().tolist())
```

This flattens the array `y` to be one-dimensional, and then turns it into a list, which `to_rgba` is happy to digest as something it can hash.